# Innodb_buffer_pool_size High but RAM usage is Low

Tags: mariadb, innodb

My app is python with mariadb on 8 Cores vCPU and 16GB RAM

I've set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 11G but RAM usage is low, never crosses 5G

My application then runs quite slow. What causes this? Any clues and guidance?

---

DB size is less than 5GB

I attached htop statistic, it seemed there're much resources avaialable .what clues we can get? [see htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it4cu.png)

Comment: How much actual data do you have, and what is the buffer pool hit rate in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`? The buffer pool is allocated up front, but physical RAM is only allocated when really using buffer pool pages. So if all your .ibd files together are only 5GB than that's how much buffer pools is going to be used max. ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe -- Well, plus the Change Buffer and other overhead.  I would guess it might get to 7GB.